# How to generate COG tiff using agisoft python API 1.8.5

Tags: python-3.x, api, image-processing, photogrammetry

**In agisoft software how to generate COG ortho ,DSM images**

Comment: https://www.agisoft.com/forum/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot generate cog tiff in Agisoft, but if you really want cog tiff that desperately, You can use another module called "rioviz".
You can check the details here https://github.com/developmentseed/rio-viz https://cogeotiff.github.io/rio-cogeo/

Comment: Thanks, It's working but can't we directly do this with Agisoft Python API Version 1.8.5

Answer (score 0):

Example of general processing workflow via Python is given here:
https://github.com/agisoft-llc/metashape-scripts/blob/master/src/samples/general_workflow.py

For further customization check the description of the related classes and methods in API Reference:
https://www.agisoft.com/pdf/metashape_python_api_2_0_1.pdf